# send mail from linux server using python script

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

need help with sending emails from linux server.

```
def send_mail():
    sendmail_location = "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
    mail = os.popen("%s -t" % sendmail_location, "w")
    mail.write("From: %s\n" % "my_mail@mail.com") #this is correct?
    for key in data.keys():
        mail.write("To: %s\n" % key)
        print(key)
        mail.write("Subject: test email script")
        mail.write("\n")
        for value in data.values():
            mail.write(value)    
            print(value)
```

but no emails in my mail box, and no errors.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you call the function. send_mail()?

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus yes, sure.

Comment: This looks like code from the 1990s. Python has had its own `smtplib` for quite a while and `os.popen` became obsolescent in the early 2.x versions.

Comment: @tripleee can i use smtplib without smtp server?

Comment: What's `data` and what do the keys look like?

Comment: If you don't have an SMTP server configured anywhere, `sendmail` won't work, either.